# Dimension of the Vector Space of Modular Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

in *A Course in Arithmetic* by Jean-Pierre Serre, he states a theorem in 3 parts:

(i) $M_{k}=0$ for k<0 and k=1.

(ii) For k=0,,2,3,4,5, $M_{k} is a vector space of dimension 1 with basis 1.

(iii) Multiplication by $\Delta$ defines an isomorphism of $M_{k-6}$ onto $M_{k}^{0}$

First assuming (i), (iii) are true, I need someone to confirm whether I understand the proof of (ii).  For $M_{k}$ where k=0,2,3,4,5, we have that $M_{k}=M_{k}^{0} \bigoplus C.G_{k}$ so by part (iii), $M_{k}=M_{k-6} \bigoplus C.G_{k}$.  Since $k\leq 5$, by part (i), $M_{k-6}=0$ so we have $M_{k}=C.G_{k}$ which is a non-zero element so $M_{k}$ is dimension 1.  Is this correct?

Next, I understand why the map from part (iii) is surjective but to prove injectivity, I need to show given f,g $\in M_{k-6}$ such that $\Phi(f)=\Phi(g)$, then $f=g$ where $\Phi$ is the multiplication by $\Delta$ map.  So $\Delta f=\Delta g$ so from the proof by Serre, $\Delta$ does not vanish on H so we can divide by $\Delta$ and get f=g so we get injectivity.  Is this correct?

Now I have questions on the Corollary which states that the space $M_{k}$ is has a basis $G_{2}^{\alpha}G_{3}^{\beta}$.  I understand Serre's proof that these family of monomials span the space but I don't get his proof for linear independence.  If we assume the monomials were not linearly independent, then one of these monomials can be expressed as a linear combination of the others.  I don't see how he goes from there to the idea that $G_{2}^{3}/G_{3}^{2} satisfies a polynomial in C (and also, I don't know what polynomial he is referring to).

Comment: Except Serre, everybody denotes the space of modular forms and cusp forms of weight $2k$ by $M_{2k}$ and $S_{2k}$. How do you prove the multiplication by $\Delta(\tau)$ is an isomorphism $M_{k} \to S_{k+12}$ ? And you have to make your own research, there are many other books on the modular forms : see Diamond & Shurman, Apostol, etc.

Comment: And yes Serre's argument for showing $G_4^\alpha G_6^\beta$ are linearly independent is valid. If they were not, the modular function  $G_4^3/G_6^2$ of weight $0$ would be the root of a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ which is absurd.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my questions! :)